# How to approach combinatorics proofs like these.

Tags: combinatorics

Okay so I have been trying to solve problems for my course and keep running into persistent issues with proofs. For example.

> **Prove the following:** $${n\choose r}={n-1\choose r-1}+{n-1\choose r}$$

I really want to be able to give nice combinatoric proofs to questions such as this one and similar but I can never get there and explain it. Could anybody help me out on how to tackle problems such as these.

It is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: taht's the Pascal triangle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle.

Comment: The general approach to such problems is to count the elements of a set in two different ways, yielding one side when you count them one way and the other side when you count the other way.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the counting argument I guess my problem is actually identifying which two ways of counting gives the required result.

Comment: Or, you pick what each side counts, and then show that the two things are equivalent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\binom n r$ means the possibilities to choose $r$ objects from $n$ distinct objects.

We can first fix one specific object, then to choose $r$ objects, we can either choose that specific object or not.

If we have chosen that specific object, then we still have $\binom {n-1}{r-1}$ possibilities to choose the other $r-1$ objects from objects except that specific object, that is $n-1$ objects; If we do not choose that specific object, then we can have $\binom{n-1}{r}$ possibilities to choose $r$ objects from the rest of $n-1$ objects.

Hence, $\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n-1}{r-1}+\binom{n-1}{r}$.

Comment: How about some paragraph breaks?

Comment: Thanks I understood that explanation very well. Is there a good way to be able to get at these proofs myself like that I always struggle to now what to do :(

Comment: @ChrisDanton To understand this kind of formula, just to remember what $\binom{n}{r}$ means, then think of some situation, hope that helps. I can elaborate more if you have more example.

Comment: That helped than you I will give it some more thought and come back later if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The left hand side obviously counts the ways to select $r$ items from $n$.

The right hand side counts ways to select the specific item and $r-1$ of the $n-1$ others, plus the ways to not select that items and select $k$ of the $n-1$ others.

These are different ways to accomplish the same task, so the counts must be equal.

$$\binom{n}{r} = \underbrace{\binom{1}{1}}_{=1}\binom{n-1}{r-1}+\underbrace{\binom{1}{0}}_{=1}\binom{n-1}{r}$$

That's it in general.   Look at what each side of the equality count and argue that they both count ways to perform the same task.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count elements of some set $A$, try to represent $A$ as a *disjoint* union of simpler sets, e.g. $A = \bigcup_{i=1}^N A_i$. Then it holds:

\begin{align}
  \#A = \sum_{i=1}^N \#A_i
\end{align}

Example. Consider the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$. Suppose that you want to count number of subsets of size $r$. You *define* the symbol $\binom{n}{r}$ as the
number of subsets of size $r$ of a set of size $n$. The set of all subsets of size $r$ can be divided into two disjoint subsets, namely the sets that contain $1$ and those that do not contain $1$. From this, we obtain the following recursion:

\begin{align}
  \binom{n}{r} &=   \#\{X : X \subset \{1,\dots,N\}, \#X = r\} \\ 
    &= \#\left(
      \{X : X \subset \{1,\dots,N\}, \#X = r, 1\in X\} \cup 
      \{X : X \subset \{1,\dots,N\}, \#X = r, 1\not\in X\}
      \right) \\
    &= \#\left(
      \{\{1\} \cup Y : Y \subset \{2,\dots,N\}, \#Y = r-1\} \cup
      \{X : X \subset\{2,\dots,N\}, \#X = r\}
      \right) \\
    &= \# \{\{1\} \cup Y : Y \subset \{2,\dots,N\}, \#Y = r-1\} +
       \# \{X : X \subset\{2,\dots,N\}, \#X = r\} \\
    &= \# \{Y : Y \subset\{2,\dots,N\}, \#Y = r-1\} +
       \# \{X : X \subset\{2,\dots,N\}, \#X = r\} \\
    &= \binom{n-1}{r-1} + \binom{n-1}{r}
\end{align}

This of course works only if there is at least one element in the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$. If $n=0$, this no longer works, but in this case it is easy to see that $\binom{0}{0} = 1$ and $\binom{0}{r} = 0$ for all other $r$.

Notice that at this point it is absolutely not necessary to know anything about other equivalent non-combinatoric definitions of $\binom{n}{r}$.